# React Load More using Hooks

Tags: reactjs

I try to do `Load More` on a list of data as written below:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import axios from "axios";
import "./style.css";

const App = () => {
  const LIMIT = 2;
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [page, setPage] = useState(1);

  const loadData = async (skip = 1, limit = LIMIT) => {
    const URL = "https://reqres.in/api/users";
    const headers = {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      Accept: "application/json"
    };

    const params = {
      page: skip,
      per_page: limit
    };

    const a = await axios.get(URL, { params, headers });
    // const b = [...new Set([...data, ...a.data.data])]; <-- setting this will thrown error
    setData(a.data.data);
    setLoading(false);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    setLoading(true);
    loadData(page);
  }, [page]);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("page", page, "data", data.length);
  }, [page, data]);

  const doReset = evt => {
    evt.preventDefault();
    setPage(1);
  };

  const doLoadMore = evt => {
    evt.preventDefault();
    setPage(page + 1);
  };

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <h1>Listing</h1>
      <button className="btn text-primary" onClick={evt => doReset(evt)}>
        Reset
      </button>
      <button className="btn text-primary" onClick={evt => doLoadMore(evt)}>
        Load More
      </button>
      {isLoading && <p>Loading..</p>}
      {!isLoading && (
        <ul>
          {data.map(a => (
            <li key={a.id}>
              {a.id}. {a.email}
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

a fully working example in [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-load-more?embed=1&file=index.js).
i think this code should be working, but is not.

```
const a = await axios.get(URL, { params, headers });
const b = [...new Set([...data, ...a.data.data])];
setData(b);
```

so please help, how to do Load More in React Hooks?

Comment: What exactly isn't working? The example seems to load the next page correctly

Comment: this example only load 2 data item at a time. what i want basically add more data into the render list. for example, 1st click add 2 data, 2nd click add 2 more data into the list so the total become 4 data at the list, etc

Comment: What is the error when using the commented code?

Comment: it will show warning: `React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'loadData'. Either include it or remove the dependency array` but if i add `loadData` into dependency, it will say `loadData should be inside useEffect callback or in its own useCallback hooks`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after a few try, i think this is the best thing i can do. make the code working but also not let the compiler warning:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useCallback } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

import Navbar from "./Navbar";

const App = () => {
  const LIMIT = 2;
  const [tube, setTube] = useState([]);
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [page, setPage] = useState(1);

  const loadData = useCallback(
    async (limit = LIMIT) => {
      setLoading(true);
      const URL = "https://reqres.in/api/users";
      const headers = {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Accept: "application/json"
      };

      const params = {
        page,
        per_page: limit
      };

      const a = await axios.get(URL, { params, headers });
      if (!a.data.data) {
        return;
      }

      setData(a.data.data);
      setLoading(false);
    },
    [page]
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!isLoading) {
      return;
    }
    setTube([...new Set([...tube, ...data])]);
  }, [data, isLoading, tube]);

  useEffect(() => {
    loadData();
  }, [loadData]);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("page", page, "data", data.length);
  }, [page, data]);

  const doLoadMore = evt => {
    evt.preventDefault();
    setPage(page + 1);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Navbar />

      <main role="main" className="container">
        <div className="starter-template text-left">
          <h1>Listing</h1>
          <button className="btn text-primary" onClick={evt => doLoadMore(evt)}>
            Load More
          </button>
          <ul>
            {tube &&
              tube.map(a => (
                <li key={a.id}>
                  {a.id}. {a.email}
                </li>
              ))}
          </ul>
          {isLoading && <p>Loading..</p>}
        </div>
      </main>
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

also i found, it could be much easier just apply this `eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps` to let the compiler ignore the warning. something like this.

```
useEffect(() => {
    setConfig({...config, params: {...params, skip}});
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, [skip]);
```

for information can be found on this:

- [how-to-fix-missing-dependency-warning-when-using-useeffect-react-hook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55840294/how-to-fix-missing-dependency-warning-when-using-useeffect-react-hook)
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/55844055/492593
- [react #14920](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/14920)

Answer (score 0):

I got your example to work by changing to this:

```
const b = [...data, ...a.data.data];
setData(b);
```

Comment: it is the same effect with `const b = [...new Set([...data, ...a.data.data])]`. 
it will show a warning in browser/compiler. i can get rid the compiler warning with `// eslint-disable-next-line` but this is not the correct way to do it i think.

Comment: I just changed my answer. I believe this is your desired behavior. It shows 2, then 4, etc

Comment: yes, it work using your code or my comment code. but my issue was, it still give me compiler warning. i believe the correct solution was to `useCallback` but i am not sure how to do it. see it [react #6903](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/6903)